# Trouble Overriding Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been researching this for two days now and nothing that I try seems to be working. All I want to do is to set an image as the background for a `jumbotron` class in bootstrap.

I have successfully done this with inline CSS, but want to avoid using that. I have tried assigning `background-image: url('link');` to the `jumbotron` class. I have assigned it to its own unique id, I've tried assigning it to #id .jumbotron together but it does not apply the image.

This is the jumbotron I want a background image on.

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbotronBackground" >
    <div class="container">
        <img id="logoMain" src="nslogo1.png" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `#jumbotron` as a reference but **it is better to just stick with classes**.

Just make sure the rule is specific enough, that you can override the property. E.g. `#jumbotronBackground.jumbotron` is higher specific than just `#jumbotronBackground` or `.jumbotron`.

If you want to override a property you can add more specifiers. Just for completion sake: There is `!important` that you can add after the attribute if the rule is less specific, it will ignore all other selectors that would otherwise apply, but this is bad practice!

```css
.jumbotron.example1 {
  height: 160px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* repeat is default, use no-repeat if you want the image to render only once */
  background-size: contain;
  /* contain will make it render so that the image will be fully contained in the corresponding element (keeps the aspect ratio), cover will make it fill 100% of the space available (keeps the aspect ratio) */
}

.jumbotron.example2 {
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  /* it will use the background-color that is defined in jumbotron you could set background-color: $color to change it */
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* here the image will be 150px wide and high */
}

.jumbotron.example3 {
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  /* it will inherit the color from the parent - here body - you could also use transparent or white */
  background-color: inherit;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  /* here the image will be full width/height, but without the aspect ratio */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron example1 jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbotronBackground">
    <div class="container">
      <img id="logoMain" src="nslogo1.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron example2 jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbotronBackground2">
    <div class="container">
      <img id="logoMain" src="nslogo1.png">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron example3 jumbotron-fluid" id="jumbotronBackground3">
    <div class="container">
      <img id="logoMain" src="nslogo1.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ive tried stacking classes and ids but nothing. i even tried adding important and nothing. im sure im just missing something but ive never had this issue before so im left scratching my head.

Comment: @Jacob I would have to look at the source directly can you provide a https://pastebin.com link of the entire source file/s (html + css)?. Or post it here (depending on the size of the files) whatever works.

Comment: I figured it out. I was not doing anything wrong with my code. my browser was not refreshing properly. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob If you found any answer to your question helpful, please have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), no obligation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start your CSS by using the `transparent` value for the `background` property followed by the URL of the background image. Please find the code below. 
Hope this code will solve your problem.

```
.jumbotron {
  background: transparent url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/417074/pexels-photo-417074.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```